# git deleting branch after 3 way merge. What does it look like as a diagram?

Tags: git, merge, branch, diagram

I've been following Scott Chacon's [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and I'm reaching the end of chapter 3 in which we have just done a three way merge. See the diagram below (my own drawn diagram not a screen grab of the book):

[image]

After doing the merge of '**master**' with '**issue53**', resulting in merge commit **c6**, the author says we can delete branch '**issue53**'.

```
git branch -d issue53
```

What actually happens to that branch under the hood and what would the resultant diagram look like? I ask this because the author does not address the issue. Would the branch still be there but just not pointed to? or is there some magic going on that I'm unaware of?

Comment: This diagram looks unlike what I am used to seeing.  In any case, when you delete a branch, the commits in that branch will persist if they are referred to by other branches, which would probably be the case here, at least for most of the commits.  Actually, even if you nuke a branch, all commits would still be listed in the reflog, at least for a time.

Comment: Tim, I simplified the diagram to cut to the core point. I'd be interested to know ow you'd draw it differently.

Comment: Hi Andrew, are you certain this is a three way merge?  From what I can see, commit `C6` only has two, not three, parents.

Comment: The text book calls it so, so I presume its correct. This is because the merge requires C2, C4 and C5.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen (and Andrew S): the term *three way merge* refers to the single ancestor plus two versions that are its inputs. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)#Three-way_merge

Comment: @torek Yes, I realized that.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Imagine this situation, if you had a file index.js and you edited it in both, c4 and c5, then the only way it can build a version of index.js for c6 is by showing how those files changed from the common ancestor c2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What actually happens to that branch under the hood

That depends on what you mean by the word *branch*.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

> and what would the resultant diagram look like?

Drawing it in ASCII rather than fancy graphics, I get:

```
C0<-C1<-C2<-C4<---C6   <-- master (HEAD)
          \      /
           C3<-C5
```

That is, *nothing* happens to the *commits* at all.  The *name* `issue53`, however, which used to point to commit `C5`, no longer exists (at all).

Since every commit in the diagram is still find-able by starting from the name `master` and working backwards, every commit remains protected from Git's garbage collection process.

Answer (score 1):

A branch in git is just a pointer to a commit, and it has a very simple implementation - it is a text file containing the checksum of a commit it is pointing to.

So in this example, you would have a file `.git/refs/heads/issue53` that represents your branch (is your branch).

And when you delete a branch in git, you delete that text file (pointer) representing that branch. In this case, `.git/refs/heads/issu53`